# I have an old iPad, it had a SIM but not cellular voice, is there a way to make calls?

Tags: ipad, sim, call

I have an old iPad Air 32 GB (about 8-10 years old I think), it had a SIM card but not cellular voice capability. Is there a way to make calls? Some app? I have tried:

```
Facetime FAIL
CallRight FAIL
```

I want to call an external number using the SIM. I tried to disable the SIM navigation and use Wi-Fi but it still failed.

Comment: What do you mean with "had sim but not cellular"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That iPad was only capable of mobile data, but not voice.  The iPad is not a phone.  To call a landline with it, you need either…

- A VoIP App like Skype with landline capability
- An iPhone with handoff so your iPad can make calls

There are “softphone” apps, but they usually integrate with a phone system (PBX) or cloud service and they usually cost money.

You might be able to install the Google Phone app, but the current App may not be supported on your version of iOS. I know Skyoe has this capability and do use it from time to time, but like the Google App, your iPad might not support it.  You will have to search for similar apps specific to your version of iOS.